# Assigning a step to a variable in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline script:

```groovy
node {
    def myStep = sh
    myStep "ls -la"
}
```

I thought steps were visible as variables and could be assigned to variables so that they can be used later (for example choosing a different step depending on some conditions).

However, this fails with:

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myStep for class: groovy.lang.Binding
  at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:232)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:282)
  at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:286)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:28)
  at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
  at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:3)
  at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
```

How can I put a step in a variable to use it later without hardcoding its name?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method in your pipeline that wraps the behavior you want. It will have access to the script variables.

```groovy
node {
  myStep("ls -la")
}

def myStep(String script) {
  sh(script)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround:

```groovy
node {
    def myStep = { script -> 
        sh script
    }
    myStep("ls -la")
}
```